# Implementing a <p-table> with a grey header

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm relatively new to angular.  I'm trying to implement a p-table with a table header that is grey.

I believe this is done with an ng-template - but I must be leaving something out.

Here's my

```
<p-table>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-rowData>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">Col 1</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>

</p-table>
```

It sort of looks okay - but it doesn't have a light grey background like other table headers do.

Furthermore I know I'm leaving something out because if I attempt to implement a body below within another ng-template like below - the body doesn't render at all.

```
<p-table>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-rowData>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body">
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign your table value in your `p-table` element.

```
<p-table [value]="products">
...
</p-table>
```

And you can use you product date in your body template through `let-product` variable in your body template

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
...
</ng-template>
```

Refernce: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-yezxqq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Documentation: [PrimeNG Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/basic)

Comment: Thank you.  This also does a great deal to push me in the right direction to understand what ng-templates are for.

Comment: Great and Thanks @Tim